# Получить УРЛ из JSON

Tags: php, json

Добрый день. После некоторых манипуляций страница на моем сайте выдает следующий JSON:

```
[{"label":"480p","type":"video/mp4","src":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=40b3f3ec143687cd&itag=59&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1482540192&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=950A43825DE9695A5D0B7A9747BE235C6AE1CD1C.271EA64678AD8F795A737050213CD6977A290655&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7y&ms=au&mt=1482525467&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","file":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=40b3f3ec143687cd&itag=59&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1482540192&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=950A43825DE9695A5D0B7A9747BE235C6AE1CD1C.271EA64678AD8F795A737050213CD6977A290655&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7y&ms=au&mt=1482525467&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","res":"480p"},{"label":"360p","type":"video/mp4","src":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=40b3f3ec143687cd&itag=18&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1482540192&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=B2737AB38C71D60CDAAB37F1EECCA68C0BCF96F1.9475E2DFC0932688178C950241DE2A2F396FE7A7&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7y&ms=au&mt=1482525467&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","file":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=40b3f3ec143687cd&itag=18&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1482540192&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=B2737AB38C71D60CDAAB37F1EECCA68C0BCF96F1.9475E2DFC0932688178C950241DE2A2F396FE7A7&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7y&ms=au&mt=1482525467&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","res":"360p"}]
```

Как мне оттуда вытащить самый первый урл (только первый, больше не надо), что находится в "src":? Разумеется, через php.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo json_decode($json, true)[0]['src'];
```

или

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $arr[0]['src'];
```

зависит от версии *PHP*

---

**[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)** —  Декодирует JSON строку

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Не поверите, решение искал около 2-х часов.

Comment: @gm-111 часто бывает, что это приходится делать не один день ;-)